# On non-existance square a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let $n$ to be a natural number . Why there is not  any integer $q$ such that
$$n^2=6q-1.$$

My attempt: If there exists this $q$, then $n$ to be odd integer. Now let $n=2k+1$. Then $4k^2+4k+1=6q-1$. So $2k^2+2k+1=3q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $n=3k\pm 1$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Then $$n^2=(3k\pm 1)^2=9k^2\pm 6k + 1=3\left(3k^2\pm 2k\right)+1,$$

whereas $6q-1=3(2q)-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Most simply, $n^2=6k-1$ implies $-1$ is  a square modulo $3$. However, the only squares modulo $3$  are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The squares modulo $6$ are $1$, $3$, and $4$. None of these is $-1 \bmod 6$.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The right side is now divisible by $3$. Can you prove that the left side cannot be divisible by $3$?

**Hint**: Take a look at the possible remainders of dividing $k$ by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

After that, consider the equation $\pmod 3$. You'll find

$$-k^2 -k +1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

And simply trying $k=0,1,2 \pmod 3$ tells you that it can never be satisfied